# do we have any plugin for karate in eclipse

Tags: karate

while coding in karate in eclipse, if there is some syntax error, i got the karate exception at token xyz. but it is difficult to identify the error. Do we have any smart plugin which we can insert in the eclipse which upfront identify the syntax error before running the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: for the latest, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76294302/143475

https://github.com/intuit/karate#ide-support

I believe that you will find the plugin you need on this page.