# Could not run mvn test on karate-template project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber, karate

I cloned the karate template i.e https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-template and I was able to run tests on my Eclipse IDE.

However I was not able to run tests using mvn test though I have mvn installed.

Just using the same POM.xml as in the template repo.

Please could someone advise what am I missing here.?

[image]

Tried mvn version 3.6.3 and also 3.9, but same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, my best guess is that you are on Java 8.

[Karate 1.4.0 requires Java 11](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.4.0).

If you use Eclipse, the [Eclipse Cucumber plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-eclipse-plugin) can be used to run Features or Scenarios if you add a Java class called `Main` to your `test` classpath in the `cucumber.api.cli` package (`src/test/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java`) with the following code:

```
package cucumber.api.cli;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.intuit.karate.cli.IdeMain.main(args);
    }   

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, after installing java 11 I am now able as mvn test and junit test , but not able to run as a cucumber feature in Eclipse IDE as I see below error.  Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main

Comment: EDIT: please also see comments under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78027412/143475