# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main Exception after upgrading to Karate 1.4.0 & Java 20

Tags: karate

After I update my pom.xml to Karate 1.4.0 & Java 20,receive below error when running a ".feature" file.

Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main

I'm running the feature file through Eclipse.

Comment: Was able to get around this exception by using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294210/could-not-run-mvn-test-on-karate-template-project/76294302#76294302