# Intellij Cucumber java plugin is not working for karate version 1.5.0 . Main class as: com.intuit.karate.cli.IdeMain

Tags: karate

Karate 1.5.0 will also change the Maven group-id from com.intuit.karate to io.karatelabs.

So will Intellij Cucumber java plugin works in 1.5.0 version?

To simply put will the workaround still work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76294302/143475

Existing config doesnt work as per workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76294302/143475

Comment: there were some complaints from intellij users: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-intellij-plugin/issues/41 - so the `IdeMain` class was removed. it is recommended that you use the official karate intellij plugin

Comment: Thank you Peter. So if I am not wrong we cant use eclipse IDE for karate 1.5.0 with the same workaround. And officially we can use only IntelliJ/VisualCode right

Comment: yes the same workaround won't work - but you always have the option of running java code from intellij or eclipse

Comment: Can you help me in redirecting to the page where we have option of running java code

Comment: refer https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution - aka the `Runner` API

Comment: Thank you @PeterThomas, Runner class is working with 1.5.0 to run tests. Can I ask you a frank question, say I want to use Eclipse with open source of karate version in future, I will be able to run karate test and get reports using Runner class and it wouldn't be affected in future karate framework upgrades. We would want to take some Major decisions based on reply. Referring to comment from : https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2478

Comment: yes. the `Runner` class is how all teams run tests in CI/CD. it is considered a "public API", it is in the official documentation - and will never change. we may just change the package name in a future release.