Run As > Cucumber Feature Does Nothing
When I am trying to run a Karate feature file using Eclipse Run As > Cucumber Feature nothing happens, no errors and no console feedback
Trying to run a Karate feature file using Eclipse Run As function
Eclipse Workspace

Have you checked the Error Log View?

It seems to work when I go through Run Configuration but actually right clicking on the feature file and clicking Run As > Cucumber Feature does nothing

@nitind there is nothing in the error log view

please refer to the comments under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78027412/143475

Hi Peter, I am able to run the karate tests if I go via Run Configuration but when I try to use the Right Click + Run As > Cucumber Feature nothing happens.

yes, I should have been more clear - the thing is IDE support for cucumber is not compatible with karate, so you have to consider karate specific plugins or use the karate java api to run tests (e.g. via JUnit)
