How to call the .scala class through java or javascript function in Eclipse IDE
I am checking the performace testing using Karate gatling. For that i created the .scala class as shown below.
package Performance

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class Testing extends Simulation {

  val create = scenario("create").exec(karateFeature("classpath:Performance/Demo.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(10) during (8 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
  )

}

Feature file Demo.feature:
Feature:

Scenario:
Given url 'https://example.com'
When method GET
Then status 200

In the POM am using the below dependencies and plugins.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 

<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <args>
                                    <arg>-Jbackend:GenBCode</arg>
                                    <arg>-Jdelambdafy:method</arg>
                                    <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
                                    <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                                    <arg>-feature</arg>
                                    <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                                    <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
                                    <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
                                </args>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>            
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${gatling.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
                        <includes>
                            <include>Performance.Testing</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>                                       
                </plugin> 
            </plugins>
        </build>

However, i wanted to call this .scala class through java or javascript function in my Eclipse IDE.
I tried some ways to call this .scala class through java by creating an object it is giving compilation errors.
Can you help me to fix this issue, how to call the .scala class through java or javascript.

Karate 1.4.1 does not support java 8. You need to either change your target JVM to 11 or downgrade the version of karate you are using if you must use 8.
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.4.1

Hi, Thanks for the response, but am using Java 17 version only, still i couldn't able to call the .scala class through a java class.

In the example you provided, the build configuration shows that you are targeting java 8... in this line here -> -target:jvm-1.8

@YarasuLavanya you can see if the Java option of karate+gatling works where you can avoid scala. use this branch of the karate-todo example, that uses karate 1.5.0.RCX - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/tree/karate-1.5

Thanks for the information @Peter but some how i wasn't able to use karate latest version 1.5.0.RC3 in my service, might be that artifact version wasn't there in repository.

@YarasuLavanya The artifact / repository issue might be due to change in  the maven group-id from com.intuit.karate to io.karatelabs for 1.5.X
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.karatelabs/karate-core/1.5.0.RC3

@PeterThomas I followed the steps you mentioned above, However, when I try to run the feature file from eclipse it is throwing the below error --> Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main

@YarasuLavanya Eclipse is not supported, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78555982/143475
