Karate 1.5.0 version returning error and not running the feature file successfully
Below error is seen on running a simple feature file:
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main

Feature file:
Feature: Demo test run

Background:
Given url 'https://reqres.in/'

Scenario: Get user details
Given path '/api/users/2'
When method GET
Then status 200
And print response
And match response.data.id == 2

pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
  <dependencies>
  
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.karatelabs/karate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.karatelabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.karatelabs/karate-junit5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.karatelabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>
</project>

Should we use the paid subscription of PRO/PLUS Karate plugin in IntelliJ only then we can run the Karate? What is the process in Eclipse?

Yes you need to use paid option in intellij with latest versions. In eclipse till 1.4.1 version you can use cucumber eclipse plugin. If you are looking for free option with latest version of Karate, you can use java runner class and specify the feature file there. Please refer this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294210/could-not-run-mvn-test-on-karate-template-project-in-eclipse

Thank you @cyrilgeorge153 for your response. Even with v 1.4.1 in eclipse am getting the reported error. Even for 1.4.1 should I use the Main class suggested ?

Yes, you need to add it. Then it will work.

Thanks a lot would try and let know here
